# How to use an array containing JButtons within a for loop to draw a grid?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jframe, jbutton

```
public void loadBoard()
{
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
     for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        buttons[row][col] = new JButton("");
            buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);
            this.add(buttons[row][col]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already managed to construct a for loop partially at the top. but im still missing some parts to make an 5 X 5 2D array of buttons.

Comment: Please give some detail to your question, else it might get closed as an un-answerable question.  I would edit your question and add the detail to it.  Please check out this link to see what detail is needed: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: what do u mean by detail? o__o

Comment: See my link above. You just post code, that's it, and you're assuming we understand just what you're trying to do without telling us explicitly.  Well, we don't, so you'll need to give us several sentences describing your problem.  Also, as has been recommended before, you'll likely get quicker and better responses if you create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  Just ask Andrew.

Comment: ok...what i am aiming for with this for loop is a 5 X 5 array of JButtons drawn by this loop

Comment: You've got 6 x 6 JButtons, not 5 x 5.  And what do you mean by array of buttons drawn by this loop.  What is "drawn" in this context? Do you want an N x N grid of JButtons?  If so, then simply place them in a GridLayout-using container.  Again, please write out several sentences, maybe even a paragraph, but tell us what you're trying to do as if we can't read your mind, as if we don't intuitively know what your code is trying to do.

Comment: ok..so i want to have a 5 X 5 grid of JButtons. I have already thought of putting the buttons in a GridLayout-using container but I can't progress to that step yet due to the fact that my loop to produce the buttons isn't working. Does anyone know how to fix my loop or what I should add to it?

Comment: Define "isn't working".  Again, details are important.

Comment: ok..my JButtons arent even showing up when I try to print them using the for loop. Is there a reason for this? And, how do you print text on the JButtons individually? Because I'm trying to create a board for jeopardy. That is the reason for the loop printing out JButtons.

Comment: For us to see what you're doing wrong, you really should create a small compilable runnable program, an SSCCE, as Andrew suggested in your other recent thread.

Comment: i actually dont know what to do at this point....cause i dont know how to do what you just said...

Comment: First, read the link: [sscce](http://sscce.org) .  Next create a small program that simply creates a JPanel, tries to add buttons onto the JPanel, then adds the JPanel to a JFrame and displays the JFrame. It shouldn't take more than 40-50 lines of code.

Comment: @Hovercraft:  "Just ask Andrew."  It's nice to know some people are listening, but it's a pity that it's the people who are already sold on the idea, rather than the ones who most need the advice.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`GridLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), or any other [`Layout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box) for that matter to lay them out.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));

for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
    {
        panel.add(buttons[row][col]);
    }
}

this.add(panel);
```

Comment: hmmm, that recommendation looks familiar.  Oh yeah, that's right; I made it about an hour ago.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I honestly didn't see it. I have a habit of not reading the extra comments that are auto-hidden. Feel free to post the answer (verbatim) and I'll vote yours up.